# Structure Nav: Output "Section" Title on both Landing and Decedents

Tags: structure

Hi all… I have a Structure organized like this:

1. Arts

   - Journals

     - Submissions
   - Books
2. Sciences

   - Journals

     - Submissions
   - Books

…etc.

In my template, I want to grab the "Section" (e.g. Arts, Sciences) that I'm in and output it at the top of the page, both on the main page and subpages.

For decedents I can do that using:

```
    {% set currentSubject = entry.getAncestors().level(1) %}
    {% for entry in currentSubject %}
    {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}
```

But if I'm on the main page (e.g. Arts, Sciences) itself getAncestors won't help. Is there a smart conditional that will give me the title of the top level page regardless of if I'm on it or a descendent of it?

For some reason, I find myself hoping this can be done without looking at segments, but maybe that's the best route for this kind of thing?

Comment: I usually end up using segments for this, something like `{% set topLevel = craft.entries.slug(craft.request.segment(1)).first() %}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for the entry's `level` property. Something like the following.

```
{% if entry.level == 1 %}
    <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
{% else %}
    <h1>{{ entry.ancestors.first.title }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about using level — that's a great solution. This is working, though I found that for the tertiary+ level we need "entry.ancestors.**first**.title" to get the right result … editing above.

Comment: Great! I pulled this out of one of my own projects where the structure was limited to two levels. Couldn't remember whether '.first' or '.last' would get you to the top level. I updated the example to use 'first'.